# Number of NaN values before first non NaN value Python dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with several columns, some of them contain NaN values. I would like for each row to create another column containing the total number of columns minus the number of NaN values before the first non NaN value.

Original dataframe:

```
ID    Value0     Value1      Value2      Value3
1       10         10           8          15 
2       NaN        45          52         NaN      
3       NaN       NaN          NaN        NaN    
4       NaN       NaN          100        150
```

The extra column would look like:

```
  ID    NewColumn

   1     4
   2     3
   3     0
   4     2
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Set the index to `ID`
- Attach a non-null column to stop/catch the `argmax`
- Use `argmax` to find the first non-null value
- Subtract those values from the length of the relevant columns

---

```
df.assign(
    NewColumn=
        df.shape[1] - 1 -
        df.set_index('ID').assign(notnull=1).notnull().values.argmax(1)
)

   ID  Value0  Value1  Value2  Value3  NewColumn
0   1    10.0    10.0     8.0    15.0          4
1   2     NaN    45.0    52.0     NaN          3
2   3     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN          0
3   4     NaN     NaN   100.0   150.0          2
```