# Python Pandas: Get number of NaN before first non NaN value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

| y |
| --- |
| NaN |
| NaN |
| 5 |
| NaN |
| 7 |

I would like to write a function that will return the number of NaN values before the first non-NaN value. Given the above example, the function should return the value 2.

I tried to solve my problem using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46926618/number-of-nan-values-before-first-non-nan-value-python-dataframe), but it did not help me much.

Edit: The values always start with a NaN. If the column is all NaN, the function should return the column length.

Comment: Always values starting by `NaN` ? If all values in column are `NaN`s it is count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) to get True/1 on the NaN values and [`cumprod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumprod.html) to get rid of all values that follow a non-NaN. Then [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html):

```
df['y'].isna().cumprod().sum()
```

output: `2`

Comment: Working if always starting `NaN`s

Comment: @jezrael it works event if there is a non-NaN first, will return 0 as it should ;)

Comment: ya, it depends what OP need. If need count first NaNs island or not.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`first_valid_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first_valid_index.html).

```
df.y.first_valid_index()
> 2
```

This grabs the index of the first non-NaN value. By default we don't need to sum if the index starts from `NaN`.

Comment: Then you need to `reset_index` first to ensure having a range index ;)

Comment: depends on what the index is, OP didn't specify if they have something other than `0-n`

Comment: Yeah, it's the default df index. Of course, I'd like to be left as it is.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) with [`Series.cummin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummin.html) and count `True`s by `sum`:

```
s = df['y'].isna().cummin().sum()
print (s)
2
```

Comment: or `df['y'].isna().cummin().sum()` :p I actually was about to update my answer when you updated yours, so not adding it not to have the same as you ;)

Comment: @mozway - ya, it is simplier